# overflow-x on <html> inside iframe also does overflow-y

Tags: iframe, css, ie-compatibility-mode

I'm using a jquery plugin which happens to apply overflow-x:hidden on the  tag, which is fair enough for it's purpose.

However oddly, when the  tag is inside an iframe, the overflow-x is acting like overflow-y as well!

This is happening in IE7 compatibility mode.

Any ideas, from my understanding, overflow-x is supported in IE7 fine.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly applying overflow-y:scroll seemed to fix it.

Comment: Interesting. I came across the same thing (but with x and y swapped), but explicitly applying overflow-x in addition to overflow-y didn't fix it.